# How to get Shopify transaction getway on thank you page?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I want to get the type of payment method chosen by the user. I have tried using

```
{{ transaction.gateway }}
```

as mentioned on [Shopify Liquid Documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/transaction#transaction-gateway). But I don't know why the value is empty. Below is the little code snippet that I have added in
`Admin->Settings->Checkout->Additional content and scripts`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var temp = " {{ shipping_method.title }} ";
var temp1 = "{{ transaction.gateway }}";
alert(temp);
alert(temp1);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{{ transactions[0].gateway }}`

Comment: Some more details please

Comment: Hey joshubrown, thanks a lot for your help :). It's working now. I wonder why this isn't mentioned in official documentation of Shopify.

Comment: Hi Josh, it is possible to use `{{ transactions[0].gateway }}` in Script Tag (I'm using a script tag api)? If not, is there a way to get selected Payment Gateway in Script Tag?